# How to reset xcalib contrast to default without seeing screen?

Tags: graphics, xcalib

I installed xcalib to adjust my screen contrast, and I executed this :

> xcalib -co 0 -a

Which set my screen contrast to 0 , and now my screen turned dark, and I don't have any clue as to how can I reset this setting ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As first enter a TTY, this you achieve by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>. There you can login whit providing your username and password. Then set the contrast back with the same command you have used to set it to zero.

```
xcalib -co 50 -a
```

Now you can logout of your TTY session by entering `exit`. Afterwards you can come back to your GUI by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, you saved my life this evening :)

Comment: No problem youre very welcome

Answer (score 9):

To reset to default use

`xcalib -c`

Even if its an old post...

Comment: How does this add anything to the accepted answer?

Comment: @M.Becerra This is indeed a tested functional alternative.

Comment: @M.Becerra I don't believe the intention was to add to the other answer, even if it uses `-c` (you'll note that the question also used `-c`, however; so, I don't think that's enough to say this answer is building off of the accepted answer). It's much simpler than the accepted answer, and it still seems to work. No need to press Ctrl+Alt+F7 or anything like that. Granted, I'm only using this answer for my own purposes (not for what the questioner wanted, exactly).

Comment: I see your point :)

Comment: This has less complexity than the accepted answer, @M.Becerra. It has less arguments and solves the problem

Comment: The accepted answer does not work in my case, this does.